# Javascript RegExp non-capturing groups

Tags: javascript, regex, capturing-group, regex-group

I am writing a set of RegExps to translate a CSS selector into arrays of ids and classes.

For example, I would like '#foo#bar' to return ['foo', 'bar'].

I have been trying to achieve this with

```
"#foo#bar".match(/((?:#)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/g)
```

but it returns ['#foo', '#bar'], when the non-capturing prefix ?: should ignore the # character.

Is there a better solution than slicing each one of the returned strings?

Comment: Here’s a one-liner: `str.replace(/[^#]+|(#[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/g, '$1').split('#').slice(1)`

Comment: split doesn't work in ie8

Comment: @webaba Why would ie8 even be relevant for anything in september 2014 unless it's a specific request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use `.replace()` or `.exec()` in a loop to build an Array.

With `.replace()`:

```
var arr = [];
"#foo#bar".replace(/#([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/g, function(s, g1) {
                                               arr.push(g1);
                                          });
```

---

With `.exec()`:

```
var arr = [],
    s = "#foo#bar",
    re = /#([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/g,
    item;

while (item = re.exec(s))
    arr.push(item[1]);
```

Answer (score 5):

It matches `#foo` and `#bar` because the *outer* group (#1) is capturing. The *inner* group (#2) is not, but that' probably not what you are checking.

If you were not using global matching mode, an immediate fix would be to use `(/(?:#)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/` instead.

With global matching mode the result cannot be had in just one line because [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) behaves differently. Using regular expression only (i.e. no string operations) you would need to do it this way:

```
var re = /(?:#)([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*)/g;
var matches = [], match;
while (match = re.exec("#foo#bar")) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
```

[See it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/fpvrv/).

Comment: No need with this to group the hash key at all (and then exclude it).

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you can do that using match(), but you can do it by using the RegExp's exec() method:

```
var pattern = new RegExp('#([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)', 'g');
var matches, ids = [];

while (matches = pattern.exec('#foo#bar')) {
    ids.push( matches[1] ); // -> 'foo' and then 'bar'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is no lookbehind assertion in Javascript RegExp, otherwise you could do this:

```
/(?<=#)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*/g
```

Other than it being added to some new version of Javascript, I think using the `split` post processing is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
"#foo#bar".match(/(?!#)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/g);  // ["foo", "bar"]
```

Comment: It does return ['foo', 'bar'], but won't search for the #, so "#foo#bar.foobar".match(/(?!#)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+/g); will return ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']

Answer (score 1):

The lookbehind assertion mentioned some years ago by mVChr is [added in ECMAScript 2018](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-lookbehind). This will allow you to do this:

`'#foo#bar'.match(/(?<=#)[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]*/g)` (returns `["foo", "bar"]`)

(A negative lookbehind is also possible: use `(?<!#)` to match any character except for #, without capturing it.)

Answer (score 0):

MDN does document that ["Capture groups are ignored when using match() with the global /g flag"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll#Better_access_to_capturing_groups), and recommends using `matchAll()`. `matchAll() isn't available on Edge or Safari iOS, and you still need to skip the complete match (including the`#`).

A simpler solution is to slice off the leading prefix, if you know its length - here, 1 for `#`.

```js
const results = ('#foo#bar'.match(/#\w+/g) || []).map(s => s.slice(1));
console.log(results);
```

The `[] || ...` part is necessary in case there was no match, otherwise `match` returns null, and `null.map` won't work.

```js
const results = ('nothing matches'.match(/#\w+/g) || []).map(s => s.slice(1));
console.log(results);
```