# Best way to store JS Regex capturing groups in array?

Tags: javascript, regex

Exactly what title asks. I'll provide some examples while explaining my question.

Test string:

```
var test = "#foo# #foo# bar #foo#";
```

Say, I want to extract all text between `#` (all `foo`s but not `bar`).

```
var matches = test.match(/#(.*?)#/g);
```

Using `.match` as above, it'll store all matches but it'll simply throw away the capturing groups it seems.

```
var matches2 = /#(.*?)#/g.exec(test);
```

The `.exec` method apparently returns only the first result's matched string in the position `0` of the array and my only capturing group of that match in the position `1`.

I've exhausted SO, Google and MDN looking for an answer to no avail.

So, my question is, is there any better way to store only the matched capturing groups than looping through it with `.exec` and calling `array.push` to store the captured groups?

My expected array for the test above should be:

```
 [0] => (string) foo
 [1] => (string) foo
 [2] => (string) foo
```

Pure JS and jQuery answers are accepted, extra cookies if you post JSFiddle with `console.log`. =]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `.exec` too like following to build an array

```
var arr = [],
    s = "#foo# #bar# #test#",
    re = /#(.*?)#/g,
    item;

while (item = re.exec(s))
    arr.push(item[1]);

alert(arr.join(' '));​
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/WDKhX/)

Found from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10864877/344304)

Well, it still has a loop, if you dont want a loop then I think you have to go with `.replace()`. In which case the code will be like

```
var arr = [];
var str = "#foo# #bar# #test#"
str.replace(/#(.*?)#/g, function(s, match) {
                           arr.push(match);
                        });
```

Check these lines from [MDN DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) which explains your query about how`exec` updates `lastIndex` property I think,

> If your regular expression uses the "g" flag, you can use the exec
> method multiple times to find successive matches in the same string.
>
> When you do so, the search starts at the substring of str specified by
> the regular expression's lastIndex property (test will also advance
> the lastIndex property).

Comment: Similar to the `.exec` loop which I found but much more simplified and elegant, looks like a suitable answer as I can access all matches and capturing groups from the `item` array.

Comment: If you want to see more js magics you can check the answers of [am-not-i-am](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1106925/am-not-i-am), it's from one of his answer. :)

Comment: Favorited his profiled to read the answers later =] Now, even after reading through the [MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) I couldn't find how `.exec` knows from where to start matching in the string (the "offset"?) every time it's invoked, well, important is that it works. I think it automatically stores the `lastIndex` property? If anyone can contribute with a comment, please do. =]

Comment: Oh damn man, I've read the first phrase of that paragraph, but I somehow missed the `the search starts at the substring of str specified by the regular expression's lastIndex property (test will also advance the lastIndex property).` (it must be the SO fomatting x]), thanks again! G'night.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure if this is the answer you are looking for but you may try the following code:

```js
var matches = [];

var test = "#foo# #foo# bar #foo#";

test.replace(/#(.*?)#/g, function (string, match) {
    matches.push(match);
});

alert(JSON.stringify(matches));
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Using `.replace` to take advantage of the global modifier, a really sweet trick (better than looping it with `.exec` which was the question). I'll +1 it for now and accept before I go to sleep if there isn't a better option (keeping this question open for a little while as it might be useful for future reference). =]

Answer (score 2):

`data.replace(/.*?#(.*?#)/g, '$1').split(/#/)`
No loops, no functions.

Comment: Also, the wrong output. Expected `["foo", "foo", "foo"]`. Actual `["foo", "foo", "foo", ""]`.

Comment: @AaditMShah Yes, that's a downside - you'd always have to pop the extra. Well spotted.

Comment: Edited the post correctly

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody arrives with a similar need to mine, I needed a matching function for a Django-style URL config handler that could pass path "arguments" to a controller. I came up with this. Naturally it wouldn't work very well if matching '$' but it wouldn't break on '$1.00'. It's a little bit more explicit than necessary. You could just return matchedGroups from the else statement and not bother with the for loop test but ;; in the middle of a loop declaration freaks people out sometimes.

```
var url = 'http://www.somesite.com/calendar/2014/june/6/';
var calendarMatch = /^http\:\/\/[^\/]*\/calendar\/(\d*)\/(\w*)\/(\d{1,2})\/$/;

function getMatches(str, matcher){
    var matchedGroups = [];
    for(var i=1,groupFail=false;groupFail===false;i++){
        var group = str.replace(matcher,'$'+i);

        groupFailTester = new RegExp('^\\$'+i+'$');

        if(!groupFailTester.test(group) ){
            matchedGroups.push(group);
        }
        else {
            groupFail = true;
        }
    }
    return matchedGroups;
}

console.log( getMatches(url, calendarMatch) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thought, though exec is as efficient.

```
var s= "#foo# #foo# bar #foo#";
s= s.match(/#([^#])*#/g).join('#').replace(/^#+|#+$/g, '').split(/#+/);
```